# How to get coordinates of closest free spot?

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I have a space:

```
[.][.][.][.][.]
[.][.][.][.][.]
[.][.][x][.][.]
[.][.][.][.][.]
[.][.][.][.][.]
```

Each `[.]` represents a spot in 2D space. (need it for 3D, but doesn't matter for now)
By `[x]` I marked "current location" (let's say it's [0, 0, 0])

So I need to find what is the position of closest "not busy" spot.

For example if I had such area:

```
[.][.][.][.][.]
[.][b][b][b][.]
[.][b][x][.][.]
[.][b][b][b][.]
[.][.][.][.][.]
```

(`[b]` for "busy")

Then I would need to get a result (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0) (because it's closest one that is free).

For now thinking to do something like this:

```
current_location = {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
radius = 0 
closest_record = nil
begin
  radius = radius + 1 
  # some way to iterate over each [x, y, z] spot within that radius until
  # closest_record = Record.where(x: x1, y: y1, z: z1).first returns nil (meaning it's free)
end until record.present?
# (that's Ruby syntax, but doesn't matter really)
```

Is there some formula to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Ruby, but in C++, you might do something like this:

```
for(int x=(radius*-1); x<=radius; ++x) {
    for(int y=(radius*-1); y<=radius; ++y) {
        for(int z=(radius*-1); z<=radius; ++z) {
            if(x==0 && y==0 && z==0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                //check location[x,y,z];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, this will check every spot in the radius, and it will start in a corner.  So, you might get a corner result when a side might be closer (depending on how you're measuring the distance... is every element with a given radius the same distance?).  Moreover, if you check `radius = 1` and find nothing, incrementing `radius` to `2` and using this structure will check everything in `radius = 1`, which was already checked.  You'll have to add some extra logic to skip these checks or potentially waste a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the distance formula?  Not sure I understand the question, but the distance between two points with coordinates (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2) is:

distance = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)